# ¿Que debo hacer para que funcione este programa? POO JAVA

Tags: java, poo

Implementa la clase Cuenta, sabiendo que:

a. Cuando se crea una cuenta, su saldo es cero.

b. Solo es posible extraer un importe menor o igual al saldo que se tenga en la cuenta.

Lo debo hacer siguiendo este anexo :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando sigo las instrucciones del ejercicio no me funciona , o sale vacio por ejemplo cuando llamo el metodo depositar , no me sale lo que deposite , me aparece "Se deposito : ".

Este es el codigo que realize :

```
public class Cuenta {

//Atributos

    private String titular;
    private double saldo;


//Constructor

public Cuenta() {

}

public Cuenta (String titular , double saldo_incial) {
    this.titular=titular;
    this.saldo = 0.0; // Cuando se crea una cuenta, su saldo es cero.

}

//Metodos

public String getTitular() {

    return this.titular;
}

public void setTitular() {
    this.titular= titular;
}

public double getSaldo() {
    return this.saldo;
}

public String toString() { 

    return "Titular : "+ this.titular + " saldo : "+ this.saldo;
}

public void depositar(double cantidad) {

    System.out.println("Se deposito : ");

}


public void retirar(double cantidad) {
    if(cantidad<=saldo) {

    System.out.println("Se extrae : ");

    }

    else {

 System.out.println("Solo es posible extraer un importe menor o igual al saldo que se tenga en la cuenta" );


}


}

}
```

---

```
public class PruebaCuenta {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Cuenta cuenta1 = new Cuenta();
    Cuenta cuenta2 = new Cuenta ("jose" , 10);
    cuenta1.getSaldo();
    cuenta2.depositar(14);

}

}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes @computer96 referente a lo que consultas sobre por que se te imprime solo  "Se deposito : "  eso se debe a que solo eso esta puesto en la impresión, si quieres que se imprima la cantidad que envías al método debes agregarla a esta salida algo así como  System.out.println("Se deposito : "+cantidad);

Comment: no estas imprimiendo el valor de cantidad, en tu metodo retirar.

Answer (score 3):

Tu metodo depositar, efectivamente, no imprime ningun valor, porque simplemente no le estas diciendo que lo imprima.

```
public void depositar(double cantidad) {
    System.out.println("Se deposito : ");
}
```

Fijate que tu println, imprime lo que vos decis que imprime, pero necesita que le pases mas cosas si queres que imprima.

Por ejemplo, si queres imprimir la cantidad que le estas pasando, deberias hacer algo como:

```
System.out.println("Se deposito : " + cantidad);
```

En esa linea, Java hara una conversion implicita de tu valor, y lo agregara a la cadena a imprimir.

No revise el resto de tu código, solo me fije en la parte que marcaste como error.

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a dejar las 2 Clases implementadas a mi manera basándome en el esquema que has presentado. Que por cierto, deberías revisar mejor, ya que veo que no le pasas parámetros requeridos.

**Clase Cuenta..**

```
public class Cuenta {
    private String titular;
    private double saldo;

    public Cuenta(String titular){
        this.titular = titular;
        this.saldo = 0.0;
    }

    public Cuenta(String titular, double saldo_inicial) {
        this.titular = titular;
        this.saldo = saldo_inicial;
    }

    public String getTitular() {
        return titular;
    }

    public void setTitular(String titular) {
        this.titular = titular;
    }

    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cuenta{" + "titular=" + titular + ", saldo=" + saldo + '}';
    }

    public void depositar(double cantidad) {
        saldo += cantidad;
    }

    public void retirar(double cantidad) {
        if (cantidad <= saldo) {
            saldo -= cantidad;
            System.out.print("Retiraste " + cantidad + " de tu cuenta. ");
            System.out.println("Tu saldo actual es de: " + saldo);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Quieres retirar mas dinero de lo permitido..");
        }

    }

}
```

**Clase PruebaCuenta..**

```
public class PruebaCuenta {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cuenta cuenta1 = new Cuenta("El Nombre");
        Cuenta cuenta2 = new Cuenta("José", 10);
        cuenta1.getSaldo();
        System.out.println(cuenta1);
        cuenta2.depositar(14);
        System.out.println(cuenta2);
        cuenta2.retirar(23);
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

```
Cuenta{titular=El Nombre, saldo=0.0}
Cuenta{titular=José, saldo=24.0}
Retiraste 23.0 de tu cuenta. Tu saldo actual es de: 1.0
```

---

**Problemas que tienes..**

> public Cuenta() { }

Este es el primero. Se requiere un Constructor que reciba el nombre del titular, y además le damos un sueldo inicial de 0 como se te pide..

```
public Cuenta(String titular){
    this.titular = titular;
    this.saldo = 0.0;
}
```

***Siguiente problema en el 2º Constructor..***

> public Cuenta (String titular , double saldo_incial) {
>
> this.titular=titular;
>
> this.saldo = 0.0; // Cuando se crea una cuenta, su saldo es cero.
>
> }

Aquí deberías pasarle el **valor** de **saldo_inicial** a tu variable **saldo**

```
public Cuenta(String titular, double saldo_inicial) {
        this.titular = titular;
        this.saldo = saldo_inicial;
    }
```

***Siguiente problema este..***

> public void setTitular() {
>         this.titular= titular;
>       }

Este **requiere** que le pasemos el **parámetro titular** así..

```
public void setTitular(String titular) {
        this.titular = titular;
    }
```

***Y por último*** estos 2 métodos **'depositar() y retirar()'**, en los cuales añadimos cantidad o retiramos.. 
Te los dejo implementados a mi manera, en los cuales añadimos o restamos esa cantidad a nuestro saldo actual..

```
    public void depositar(double cantidad) {
        saldo += cantidad;
    }

    public void retirar(double cantidad) {
        if (cantidad <= saldo) {
            saldo -= cantidad;
            System.out.print("Retiraste " + cantidad + " de tu cuenta. ");
            System.out.println("Tu saldo actual es de: " + saldo);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Quieres retirar mas dinero de lo permitido..");
        }

    }
```